# How can I remove body from a Page in OrchardCMS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I currently have 2 page types in my Orchard CMS setup. One is for the front page, one for a detail page. On the front page, I have removed the body from being displayed, so that it just shows 2 HTML widgets.

Is there a way so that when someone edits this page, they don't get a body section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the **Body Part** from the page content type you use for the front page. This way people who edit this page won't see the editor for body content and the body won't be rendered at all.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

A placement file might also do the trick: placement also works for the admin ui... That could enable you to make it show or not without requiring two different content types.